# realpath command not found

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have debian squeeze amd64. My current shell is bash. If I write the following in my terminal, it works:

```
$ uname -a
Linux core 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Fri May 10 08:43:19 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                     
$ echo $(realpath test.sh)                                                                                                                                                     
/home/ffortier/test.sh
```

My test.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(realpath "$1")
```

If I try to execute the following, I get an error

```
$ ./test.sh test.sh 
./test.sh: line 2: realpath: command not found
```

How can I use the realpath command within a bash file?

**Additional Information**

```
$ type -a realpath
realpath is a function                                                                                                                                                                        
realpath ()                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                             
    f=$@;                                                                                                                                                                                     
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then                                                                                                                                                                      
        base="";                                                                                                                                                                              
        dir="$f";                                                                                                                                                                             
    else                                                                                                                                                                                      
        base="/$(basename "$f")";                                                                                                                                                             
        dir=$(dirname "$f");                                                                                                                                                                  
    fi;                                                                                                                                                                                       
    dir=$(cd "$dir" && /bin/pwd);                                                                                                                                                             
    echo "$dir$base"                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is realpath a actual command or a script? I would check to see where it is coming from.

```
$ type -a realpath
```

I'm not familiar with this tool, and so it's likely not part of your normal distribution, perhaps it's installed in a non-standard location which isn't present on Bash's `$PATH` but is within your login environment's `$PATH`.

In any event, the above `type` command will show you where the command is coming from, at which point you can alter the method you're calling it in your script like so:

```
echo $(/path/to/realpath test.sh)
```

Or amend your script's `$PATH` so that it also includes this non-standard location.

#### Functions in the shell

Much of your environment does not get called when you invoke a shell script. If you think about this, this makes a lot of sense, since you generally don't want scripts to have all the additional baggage that a user's environment may have.

You can either determine which source file is providing this function and either source it, or simply instruct Bash to incorporate your login environment.

```
#!/bin/bash -l
echo $(realpath "$1")
```

Comment: It's a function, see edit

Comment: @Francis - yeah the functions are not included when you invoke your script. You'll need to source them if you want them to come along. Find out which file is providing the function and source it. If you just want your whole env. then amend your call to bash, `#!/bin/bash -l`.

Comment: How can I find where this function comes from?

Comment: @Francis - `grep realpath $HOME/.*`.

Comment: @slm - `realpath` is - at least - a GNU coreutil since Jan 2012. But `command -v` would do the same as `type` in your example while offering the added advantage of correctly handling any other POSIX compliant shell as well.

Comment: @mikeserv - thanks, when I wrote this up I was still using Fedora 14 which did not include `realpath`. My Fedora 19 system does now include this tool. Also notice the OP was using a Debian w/ 2.6 kernel, so his system too would've been missing `realpath` given its age.

Comment: Oh gee, i didnt look at the date. My bad, @slm. Definitely your answer worked anyway - it was accepted for a reason. Im just a portablity snob. I dont even know how i landed on the answer, actually - it was an open tab in the browser for some reason. Speaking of which - not even *today's* Debian yet includes GNU `realpath` so it would be irrelevant anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv - yeah I was surprised, this is an old-ish Q now, but the info about `command` was still useful to me. It's a more portable way to do what I was showing across POSIX shells.

Comment: `command` is pretty cool. In `bash/GNU sh` it actually *is* `type` but, for instance, in `ksh` it is `whence` - its basically what youre used to already but with a standardized name. Less to remember once you manage to remember it...

Answer (score 35):

There are at least two programs called `realpath`:

- An old program from back when GNU coreutils didn't include `readlink -f`. It is now deprecated in favor of `readlink -f`, so many distributions have stopped carrying it.
- The `realpath` program introduced in GNU coreutils 8.15. This is too old to be in Debian squeeze or even wheezy; at the time of writing, [Debian unstable doesn't ship it either](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=693211). This program is very close to `readlink -f`.

For some reason, you have a shell function which partly emulates the behavior of `realpath`. This emulation is partial: if you call it on a symbolic link, it doesn't follow the symbolic link.

Since this is a shell function, presumably loaded from or via `.bashrc`, it's only available to code running in your interactive shell. If you want it to be available to other programs, assuming you're running Linux, create a script that emulates `realpath`:

```
#!/bin/sh
readlink -f -- "$@"
```

(This doesn't emulate `realpath`'s rarely-used command line options.)

Comment: I cannot find any evidence in the coreutils git repo that the `realpath` program is considered deprecated by coreutils, or that it is not built by default. So Debian must be removing it.

Comment: @Kaz Oh, well, just to complicate matters, coreutils recently (8.15) introduced a `realpath` binary, which is close but not exactly identical to `readlink -f`. Debian stable carries 8.13. Debian unstable [chose to keep the legacy program](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=693211).

Comment: It wasn't *that* recently - it was Jan 2012. http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7076

Comment: @mikeserv Far too recent for the distribution in the question (Debian squeeze). Even too recent for the current Debian stable.

Comment: That's kinda scary. How old is their `openssl`?

Comment: @mikeserv If you want to continue this completely unproductive discussion about stable vs rolling distributions, take it to chat.

Comment: I don't understand why you believe it unproductive - it is on topic. In any case, don't get your feelings hurt, man. I'm just some jerk on the internet. I'm willing to bet there are plenty of stable release distros packing a later than 2012 coreutils anyway.

Comment: Debian is now moving to GNU realpath. Why do you say it's deprecated? AFAICS GNU realpath has features (like `--rel-path`) which GNU readlink doesn't have. Many systems have a `readlink(1)` that is just an interface to `readlink(2)` (while `realpath(1)` is an interface to `realpath(3)`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't say that GNU realpath is deprecated, I say that the old `realpath` (which is what the distribution in the question has) is deprecated.

Comment: Looks like Debian ships both now?

Answer (score 30):

It works only in shell, because script file has different scope and doesn't have access to your local functions and aliases defined in your *rc* files. And `realpath` command actually doesn't exist in your system.

So either install `realpath` from the package, define your own function (as part of the script, check some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17744637/55075)) or source the *rc* file in your script where it's defined (e.g. `. ~/.bashrc`).

---

Here are the steps to install `realpath` if it's not present:

- Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install coreutils`
- OS X: `brew install coreutils`

#### Ubuntu & Debian

On Debian or Ubuntu it seems the `realpath` should be installed by default. I've checked in the recent Debian 8 (Jessie) and it seems to have `coreutils` installed by default.

Tested using fresh VM images:

```
$ vagrant init debian/jessie64 && vagrant up --provider virtualbox && vagrant ssh
$ vagrant init ubuntu/vivid64 && vagrant up --provider virtualbox && vagrant ssh
```

Then in VM:

```
$ type -a realpath
realpath is /usr/bin/realpath
```

Instead of `realpath`, you can also use `readlink -f file` (or `greadlink`) provided by `coreutils` package as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ sudo apt-get install realpath
```

Comment: This worked for me (vs sudo apt-get install coreutils)