# How to list all files in a directory with absolute paths

Tags: command-line, ls, filenames

I need a file (preferably a .list file) which contains the absolute path of every file in a directory.

> Example dir1: file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

`listOfFiles.list`:

```
/Users/haddad/dir1/file1.txt
/Users/haddad/dir1/file2.txt
/Users/haddad/dir1/file3.txt
```

How can I accomplish this in linux/mac?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
ls -d "$PWD"/* > listOfFiles.list
```

Comment: would this work in red hat linux?

Comment: don't know, never used red hat

Comment: That command works in **any** Linux or UNIX operating system. If you want to get one file per line, you need to use `ls -d -1 $PWD/*`

Comment: @MelBurslan for me it prints one path per line without the extra argument

Comment: @MelBurslan it works fine without the argument for me as well

Comment: if your file names are long or terminal width is narrow,, yes, that will be the case, but say you maximized the terminal window to occupy the whole screen or your file names (including the path) are really short, that will not hold true. `-1` option guarantees you get one filename per line

Comment: @MelBurslan 's addition is only needed if output is to a termiinal. `ls` detects if output is is to a file or terminal.

Comment: this will fail if there are many thousands of files in the directory, i.e. enough to exceed the maximum command line size (made more likely by the fact that the shell is expanding the filenames with full path).  @Andy Dalton's `find` answer is a better solution, as it won't fail no matter how many files are to be listed.

Answer (score 58):

You can use find.  Assuming that you want only regular files, you can do:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f > listOfFiles.list
```

You can adjust the type parameter as appropriate if you want other types of files.

Comment: +1 for pointing a more future-proof solution that `ls`. This `find` does recurse the subdirectories, for non-recursive you need to add `-maxdepth 1` before `-type` argument.

Comment: @AndyDalton How to get the same to an array in bash

Comment: adding '| sort' before redirection will also sort the output

Comment: `find "$(pwd)" -type f > listOfFiles.txt` will list files w.r.t. working directory. Note: the file `listOfFiles.txt` will also be listed in this approach.

Comment: @Hari `.` might be easier to read than `"$(pwd)"`.

Comment: @stackprotector, Yes, `.` is an useful option too. `"$(pwd)"` lists the files with their entire paths. That could be useful according to one's requirement.

Comment: @stackprotector @Hari I tried `.` from `zsh` and it gives relative paths, whereas `$(pwd)` gives absolute paths

Answer (score 17):

Note that in:

```
ls -d "$PWD"/* > listOfFiles.list
```

It's the shell that computes the list of (non-hidden) files in the directory and passes the list to `ls`. `ls` just prints that list here, so you could as well do:

```
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/* > listOfFiles.list
```

Note that it doesn't include hidden files, includes files of any type (including directories) and if there's no non-hidden file in the directory, in Bourne/POSIX/rc-like shells, you'd get `/current/wd/*` as output. Also, since the newline character is as valid as any in a file path, if you separate the file paths with newline characters, you won't be able to use that resulting file to get back to the list of files reliably.

With the `zsh` shell, you could do instead:

```
print -rNC1 $PWD/*(ND-.) > listOfFiles.list
```

Where:

- `-rC1` prints `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn.
- `-N`, output records are NUL-delimited instead of newline-delimited (lines) as NUL is the only character that can't be found in a file name.
- `N`: expands to nothing if there's no matching file (`nullglob`)
- `D`: include hidden files (`dotglob`).
- `-.`: include only *regular* files (`.`) after symlink resolution (`-`).

Then, you'd be able to do something like:

```
xargs -0 rm -f -- < listOfFiles.list
```

To remove those files for instance.

You could also use the `:P` modifier in the glob qualifiers to get the equivalent of `realpath()` on the files expanded from the globs (gets a full path exempt of any symlink component):

```
print -rNC1 -- *(ND-.:P) > listOfFiles.list
```

Comment: Using `printf` has the added bonus that you won't get a 'command line too long' error if you have thousands of files as `printf` is not run as a separate process.

Comment: @AdrianPronk, yes, except in shells where `printf` is not built-in like `pdksh` and some of its derivatives or most versions of the Bourne shell. One drawback compared to `ls -d` is that if there's no non-hidden file in there, it will print `/path/to/*` while `ls` will give you an error about that file not existing instead.

Answer (score 11):

To see just regular files --

```
find "$PWD" -type f  > output
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way with `tree`, not mentioned here, it goes recursively and unlike find or ls you don't have any errors (like: `Permission denied`, `Not a directory`) you also get the absolute path in case you want to feed the files to `xargs` or other command

```
tree -fai /pathYouWantToList >listOfFiles.list
```

the options meaning:

```
-a     All  files  are  printed.  By default tree does not print hidden files (those beginning with a dot
       `.').  In no event does tree print the file system constructs `.'  (current  directory)  and  `..'
       (previous directory).

-i     Makes tree not print the indentation lines, useful when used in conjunction with the -f option.

-f     Prints the full path prefix for each file.
```

To install `tree`:

`sudo apt install tree` on Ubuntu/Debian

`sudo yum install tree` on CentOS/Fedora

`sudo zypper install tree` on OpenSUSE

Comment: tree: command not found

Comment: @rogerdpack 
`sudo apt install tree` on Ubuntu

`sudo yum install tree` on CentOS

`sudo zypper install tree` on OpenSUSE

Comment: `brew install tree` on Mac

Comment: Is there a built-in way of not outputting the directory information (e.g. "1 directory, 8 files")?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [`realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) or [`readlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html) this [naughty](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) way:

```
ls | xargs realpath
```

When `ls` prints to a TTY it formats the file names in columns, but when it's writing to a file, pipe, or other non-TTY it behaves like `ls -1` and prints one file name per line. You can check this by running `ls | cat` in place of `ls`.<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745409/4970442)</sup>

- [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) build and execute command lines from standard input.
- [`realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html): return the canonicalized absolute pathname
- [`readlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html): read value of a symbolic link
- [Use `realpath --`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341934/209677) to make it treat everything that follows as parameters instead of options, if files could have " `-something`".
- If some files have spaces you could:

  ```
  ls | xargs -I {} realpath -- {}
  ```

Comment: realpath: command not found

Comment: @rogerdpack do you have [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) package installed? I get that info with `dpkg -S /usr/bin/realpath`. Check out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101559/209677).

Comment: Wonderful. First solution I found that works recursively:
`ls -R $PWD | xargs realpath | grep yaml`

Comment: @Feocco not if your filenames contain spaces...

Comment: @roaima I added a slightly more complex alternative with for those cases

Answer (score 2):

In a past Linux environment, I had a `resolve` command that would standardize paths, including making a relative path into an absolute path.  I can't find it now, so maybe it was written by someone in that organization.

You can make your own script using functions in the Python or Perl standard libraries (and probably other languages too).

`resolve.py` :

```
#!/bin/env python

import sys
import os.path

for path in sys.argv:
    print os.path.abspath(path)
```

`resolve.pl` :

```
#!/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use Cwd qw ( abs_path );

foreach (@ARGV) {
    print abs_path($_), "\n";
}
```

Then, you would solve your problem with:

```
resolve.py * > listOfFiles.list
```

---

With this command, you can also do things like this:

```
cd /root/dir1/dir2/dir3
resolve.py ../../dir4/foo.txt
# prints /root/dir1/dir4/foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive files can be listed by many ways in linus. Here i am sharing one liner script to clear all logs of files(only files) from /var/log/ directory and second check recently which logs file has made an entry.

First:-

```
find /var/log/ -type f  #listing file recursively
```

Second:-

```
for i in $(find $PWD -type f) ; do cat /dev/null > "$i" ; done #empty files recursively
```

Third use:-

```
ls -ltr $(find /var/log/ -type f ) # listing file used in recent
```

note: for directory location you can also pass $PWD instead of /var/log.

Answer (score 1):

I find `bash find $(pwd)` works well. Also, `ls | xargs realpath` works. You can add any other flags to the latter example as well as the first.

Answer (score 0):

**To list the full path of all commands (apps/programs) accessible to the user...** *(revised to address most, but not all limitations outlined in the comments)*

```
eval ls -d $(echo $PATH | sed -e 's|^:|.:|'  -e 's|:$|:.:|'  -e 's|:|/{.,}[[:word:]]* |g') 2>/dev/null | sort
```

***NOTE***
*The `PATH` variable would normally have a colon (`:`) either at the beginning or at the end, but not both. A colon at the beginning or end signifies to search the current directory as well. Standard practice is for it to be at the end so as to never override standard utility programs. The `sed` substitutions here handle either case.*

**Explanation...**

- `eval`
  Frankly, I don't know why `eval` is needed here, but it is. Without it, I get...

> ls: cannot access './{.,}[[:word:]]*': No such file or directory
>
> ls: cannot access '/home/alpha/bin/{.,}[[:word:]]*': No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access '/usr/local/sbin/{.,}[[:word:]]*': No such file or directory
>
> ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/{.,}[[:word:]]*': No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access '/usr/sbin/{.,}[[:word:]]*': No such file or directory
>
> ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/{.,}[[:word:]]*': No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access '/sbin/{.,}[[:word:]]*': No such file or directory
>
> ls: cannot access '/bin/{.,}[[:word:]]*': No such file ordirectory

- `ls -d`
  List directories. The `-d` option doesn't really just list directories. By appending `/*` to each directory (see below), we will get the contents of the directories.
- `$( ... )`
  Perform the commands inside parens and replace the `$( ... )` with the results for `ls` to use.

  - `$(echo :$PATH | sed -e 's|^:|.:|'  -e 's|:$|:.:|'  -e 's|:|/{.,}[[:word:]]* |g')`

    - Produces a space-separated list of directory patterns like...

      ```
      ./{.,}[[:word:]]* /home/alpha/bin/{.,}[[:word:]]* /usr/local/sbin/{.,}[[:word:]]* /usr/local/bin/{.,}[[:word:]]* /usr/sbin/{.,}[[:word:]]* /usr/bin/{.,}[[:word:]]* /sbin/{.,}[[:word:]]* /bin/{.,}[[:word:]]*
      ```
    - `echo $PATH`
      The PATH environment variable contains a colon-separated list of all directories that will be searched for commands.
    - `sed`
      Stream editor utility. The following `-e` substitution options are processed sequentially so that the results of each are available to the next. Thus, the `:.:` inserted by the second one allow the colons be replaced by the pattern in the third.
    - `-e 's|^:|.:|'`
      If `PATH` starts with a colon(`:`), replace it with `.:`
    - `-e 's|:$|:.:|'`
      If `PATH` ends with a colon(`:`), replace it with `:.:`
    - `-e 's|:|/{.,}[[:word:]]* |g`
      Replace every colon (`:`) with `/{.,}[[:word:]]*`. This pattern includes files beginning with a dot (`.`) followed by any number of alphanumeric or underscore characters. The extra comma (`,`) in `{.,}` is a quirk of `bash 5.0.18` as it is expecting a comma separated list or range. We are using brace substitution here to make the dot (`.`) optional.
    - `2>/dev/null`
      Discard error messages.
- `| sort`
  Optionally, sort the output from the previous command.

Comment: That assumes the components of `$PATH` don't contain space, tab, newline and wildcard characters (and backslash in bash 5.0) and that `$PATH` doesn't contain the current directory (as in `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:`). That will also not list the commands whose name starts with a `.`. You're also not adding `/*` to the last component. In `zsh`, you'd just do: `print -roC1 $commands`.

Comment: Standard practice is to _not_ include the current directory in `$PATH`.  Also, if you don't know why you need `eval`, then you probably should not be using `eval` as it may be doing things that you are not aware of.  Using `eval` to perform the task of listing files in a directory seems rather odd to me.  It's also unclear why you are involving `$PATH` here at all.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Thank You! I've revised it to address most of these limitations. At the moment, don't know of a practical way to handle tab, newline, etc. in a command list like this. Your improvements are welcome.

Comment: @Kusalananda  I make every effort not to use `eval` but it is required here. I would welcome any working modification that eliminates it.

Answer (score 0):

[`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), a `find` alternative, can be used (replace `PATH`):

```
fd . PATH --type file --absolute-path --max-depth 1 > list-of-files.txt
```