# dirname invalid option `b`

Tags: bash

Why am I getting this error, I am trying to source this set.conf

```
user@connect:~/testenv$ source $(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)"/set.conf"
dirname: invalid option -- 'b'
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
-bash: /home/tempuser/set.conf: No such file or directory
```

I tried adding -- $0 on command prompt it works well but. How can I run this in script?

Comment: Care to tell us what $0 is?

Comment: $0 is the filename of the current script. (src: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$0` inside a script is the script's name.

At the prompt, it's the shell's name, which is probably `-bash` in your case.

`dirname` is treating the leading dash as introducing a command line option, `-b`, which it doesn't support.

1. The code you're using won't work at the prompt.  You could paste it inside a file and run the file instead.
2. Try `dirname -- $0` instead: most commands let you write `--` to make it treat everything that follows as parameters instead of options.  In this case, it won't fix the problem, but it should make it clearer what the problem is.

Comment: it got executed, but as you said it is working in bash prompt but it is not getting executed in the actual script file.

Comment: How can I execute it on the script....

Comment: Nice & intuitive answer.