# How can I safely ensure a variable contains only a valid filename?

Tags: shell-script, centos, files, security, rm

Given the script below, how can I ensure that the argument only contains a valid filename within `/home/charlesingalls/` and not a path (`../home/carolineingalls/`) or wildcard, etc?

I only want the script to be able to delete a single file from the given hard-coded directory. This script will run as a privileged user.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f /home/charlesingalls/"$1"
```

Comment: If you don't want to support "foo/bar", just check that it doesn't contain `/`. Wildcards aren't interpreted inside quotes.

Comment: If you're deleting a **file**, don't use `-r` with `rm`.  `rm -r` is for recursive deletion of a directory and all files and directories beneath it.  It is only useful when deleting directories.  More generally, don't cargo-cult.  i.e. don't just copy things that look useful into your command line or script without understanding what they do or how they work.  The plane gods that bring the magic cargo can get angry and delete all your files.

Comment: Good point regarding the -r flag - I do understand its use, just wasn't thinking clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to delete a file in `/home/charlesingalls` (and not a file in a subdirectory) then it's easy: just check that the argument doesn't contain a `/`.

```
case "$1" in
  */*) echo 1>&2 "Refusing to remove a file in another directory"; exit 2;;
  *) rm -f /home/charlesingalls/"$1";;
esac
```

This runs `rm` even if the argument is `.` or `..` or empty, but in that case `rm` will harmlessly fail to delete a directory.

Wildcards are not relevant here since no wildcard expansion is performed.

This is safe even in the presence of symbolic links: if the file is a symbolic link, the symlink (which is in `/home/charlesingalls`) gets removed, and the target of that link is not affected.

Note that this assumes that `/home/charlesingalls` cannot be moved or changed. That should be ok if the directory is hard-coded in the script, but if it's determined from variables then the determination might no longer be valid by the time the `rm` command runs.

Based on the [additional information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296750/how-can-i-safely-ensure-a-variable-contains-only-a-valid-filename/296922#comment521455_296922) that the argument is a virtual host name, you should do whitelisting rather than blacklisting: check that the name is a sensible virtual host name, rather than just banning slashes. I check that the name starts with a lowercase letter or digit and that it does not contain characters other than lowercase letters, digits, dots and dashes.

```
LC_CTYPE=C LC_COLLATE=C
case "$1" in
  *[!-.0-9a-z]*|[!0-9a-z]*) echo >&2 "Invalid host name"; exit 2;;
  *) rm -f /home/charlesingalls/"$1";;
esac
```

Comment: In this case, the files are web server configuration files that have been generated by a previous process. They all have the same level of importance (each one constitutes a virtual host). However, the directory they exist in is adjacent to similar directories, and they all exist under a directory that is owned by the web server. This particular script is meant to allow deletion of virtual host configs under a certain directory only.

Comment: does this approach make sense to you provided that use case?

I appreciate your experience and will admit there are definitely times I've "brought a bazooka to a gunfight" to automate something in linux.

Comment: @AaronCicali Why can the script delete any of the host configs and not just one that belongs to the entity that made the original request? Why wasn't the virtual host name validated first (then it wouldn't contain any special characters)?

Comment: The entity that makes the original request is a GUI that does indeed have permission to remove any of the virtual hosts in that folder. The virtual host name is validated first. It comes from a list of previously created virtual hosts (domain names). I believe it is the job of this script to ensure that it is as secure as it can be without relying on the security of another part of the application. Namely, that it can only delete files from within this specific directory. It will also need to do some additional cleanup work.

Comment: @AaronCicali Ok, as an additional sanity check this makes sense. In this case you should whitelist: only accept names that look like plausible host names. If you don't allow subdomains, you might even forbid `.`

Comment: You are assuming that `rm` does what it normally does. In a friendly environment, that's usually the case (but the user can still have an alias or something that messes up that assumption). In an unfriendly environment, maybe not. I suggest explicitly using [`/bin/rm`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#BINESSENTIALUSERCOMMANDBINARIES) instead. That will work on any system adhering to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (which requires `rm` to be in /bin) and at least pretty much requires root to be an accomplice to the attacker (or a privilege escalation attack) to go awry.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If you can't trust `rm`, you can't trust `sh` either. When you run a shell script under different privileges, it's vital to sanitize the environment before running the script, not only for `PATH` but also for `ENV`, etc.

Comment: True to a point, but it isn't entirely uncommon for people to alias `rm` to something else, whereas I don't think I've ever seen anyone suggest aliasing the shell itself to something else. Explicitly specifying /bin/rm avoids the possibility of an alias *and* largely as a happy coincidence protects against a rouge `rm` that is somehow earlier in $PATH.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling In this context, the code is not run from a script, not from an interactive shell, so the only aliases would be ones defined in the script itself, and aliasing `rm` would fall under “duh, don't shoot your own foot”.

Comment: @Gilles Just looking at this answer again. That first code snippet looks dangerous. Suppose the value provided for $1 were " * -r". Your second code snippet would resolve this, but for anyone referencing this post without a good understanding, it could spell trouble.

Comment: @AaronCicali What danger are you thinking of? With the first snippet, if the argument is `* -r` then the code deletes the file called `/home/charlesingalls/* -r`, if it exists. Neither snippet will ever do anything other than deleting a file in the directory `/home/charlesingalls`.

Comment: @Gilles There's a leading space to that value. This would result in "rm -f /home/charlesingalls * -r". That would delete the home directory as well as anything in the directory of the running script, right? Removing the asterisk would work as well.... just providing " -r" for the value would cause the script to delete the home directory. Oh no Charles!

Comment: @AaronCicali No, the command deletes the one file whose name is the argument, even when the argument begins with a space. The expansion `$1` is in double quotes, so no word splitting or wildcard expansion occurs.

Comment: @Gilles Ah, I see. Perfect. Thanks for taking the time to educate me.

Answer (score 11):

**This answer assumes that `$1` is allowed to include subdirectories.  If you are interested in the simpler case where `$1` should be a simple directory name, then see one of the other answers.**

---

Wildcards are not expanded when in double-quotes.  Since `$1` is in double-quotes, wildcards are not a problem.

Both `../` and symlinks can obscure the *real* location of a file.  Shown below are tests to determine if the file is really, not just seemingly, under the path we want.

### Newer systems: using `realpath`

As for finding out if the file is really if the file is really under  `/home/charlesingalls/` or not, you can use `realpath`:

```
realpath --relative-base=/home/charlesingalls/ "/home/charlesingalls/$1"  | grep -q '^/' && exit 1
```

The above runs `exit 1` if the file specified by `$1` is anywhere other than under the directory `/home/charlesingalls/`.  `realpath` canonicalizes the whole path, eliminating both symlinks and `../`.

`realpath` is part of GNU coreutils and should be available on any Linux system.

`realpath` requires [GNU coreutils 8.15 (Jan 2012) or better](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7076).

#### Examples

To demonstrate how realpath follows `../` to determine the real location of a file (for examples, the `-q` option to grep is omitted so that the actual output of grep is visible):

```
$ touch /tmp/test
$ realpath --relative-base=$HOME "$HOME/../../tmp/test" | grep '^/' && echo FAIL
/tmp/test
FAIL
```

To demonstrate how it follows symlinks:

```
$ ln -s /tmp/test ~/test
$ realpath --relative-base=$HOME "$HOME/test" | grep '^/' && echo FAIL
/tmp/test
FAIL
```

### Older systems: using `readlink -e`

`readlink` is also capable of cononicalizing a path, following both symlinks and `../`:

```
readlink -e "$HOME/test" | grep -q "^$HOME" || exit 1
```

Using the same example files:

```
$ readlink -e "$HOME/../../tmp/test" | grep "$HOME" || echo FAIL
FAIL
$ readlink -e "$HOME/test" | grep "^$HOME" || echo FAIL
FAIL
```

In addition to being available on older GNU systems, versions of `readlink` are available on BSD.

Comment: My Ubuntu 14.04's `coreutils` does not have `realpath`

Comment: @heemayl  OK.  I just investigated and   `realpath` was [introduced](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101559/53604) in GNU coreutils 8.15 which was released on [06 Jan 2012](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7076).

Comment: This seems to be more of what I'm looking for, but unfortunately my Centos 6.5 server does not have realpath. I'm not in a position to install it. Googling turns up mentions of "readlink -f" superceding realpath, but I've yet to make it work.

Comment: @AaronCicali I just added examples using `readlink -f`.  (I am not sure which version of `readlink` Centos uses.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for all of your effort @John1024. Let me do some tinkering to make sure I understand this entirely before accepting.

Comment: The subtitle mentions `-f` ("all but the last component must exist") and the examples use `-e` ("all components must exist"), which is a bit confusing.

Comment: This is definitely the answer I was looking for. Thanks @John1024!

Comment: @AaronCicali This is definitely not the answer you need, because it's dangerously wrong. You **must not resolve symbolic links**. The target of the symbolic link may change between the time you check it and the time you use it. (It's a [well-known category of design errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use)). Besides, it doesn't make sense to resolve symlinks since `rm` acts on the argument itself, not its target.

Comment: Hint: Use `grep -q` to keep `grep` from outputting matching lines. You still get the exit status so `&&` and `||` still work exactly like you are used to.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I liked the output of matching lines for the illustrative examples.  But, for the working code, you are absolutely right that `-q` is the way to go.  So, except for the examples, the answer is now updated to use `-q`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to forbid paths completely, the simplest way is to test if the variable contains a slash (`/`). In bash:

```
if [[ "$1" = */* ]] ; then...
```

This will block all paths, though, including `foo/bar`. You could test for `..` instead, but that would leave the possibility of symlinks pointing to directories outside the target path.

If you only want to allow deleting a single file, I don't think you should be using `rm -r`.

---

Also, depending on what you are doing, you could use the system's file permissions to only allow deleting files the user could delete themselves.
Something like this:

```
su charlesingalls -c "rm /home/charlesingalls/'$1'"
```

Though as @Gilles commented, this has a quoting issue: it will fail if `$1` contains a single quote, so the variable should be tested for that first (with e.g. `if [[ "$1" = *\'* ]] ; then fail...` or rather by whitelisting a sensible set of characters), or the file name passed through an environment variable with e.g.

```
file="$1" su charlesingalls -c 'rm "/home/charlesingalls/$file"'
```

Comment: Good point regarding the -r flag, that really shouldn't be there. Removing now...

Comment: Note that your `su` command is broken because the quoting is wrong. You're executing a command with the argument interpolated as a shell snippet. E.g. if the argument is `$(touch foo)` then your code runs `touch foo`.

Comment: @Gilles, crap, I knew there had to be something wrong. nested quoting is not my favourite friend. I _think_ the current version works better, double quotes will evaluate the variable in the outer shell, and single quotes keep it from being evaluated in the inner shell. No warranty.

Comment: @ilkkachu That version fails if the argument contains a single quote. (But only in that case, which makes it a lot easier to validate than when using double quotes.) It's impossible to directly interpolate an arbitrary string. You need to either massage the string (e.g. replace all `'` by `'\''`) or pass it through another channel such as an environment variable (which is what I'd do here: `file_to_remove="$1" su -c 'rm "/home/charlesingalls/$file_to_remove"'`). It turns out that the file name is supposed to be a virtual host name, so rejecting all special characters would also be ok here.